# Red5 latest svn: configuring tomcat as Java EE-Container

Tags: java, tomcat, red5

Latest svn version of red5 does not come with a default Java EE container.
I want to configure Tomcat as the Java EE container is order to be able to execute Jsp/Servlet pages on port 5080.

These are the exact steps i took:

1. svn checkout
2. ant prepare
3. ant dist
4. copied the following files to red5/dist/plugins directory:
   catalina.jar
   jasper-el.jar
   jasper-jdt.jar
   jasper.jar
   tomcat-coyote.jar
   tomcatplugin-1.0.jar
5. copied jee-container.xml from the tomcatplugin
   to the red5/dist/conf dir.
6. made sure RED5_HOME environment variable is properly configured
7. started red5.sh

red5 won't start.

the full output of red5.sh script is at the following url:

http://pastebin.ca/1934429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the following jar:

```
tomcat-juli-slf4j.jar
```

I just copied it from an old red5 installation and it worked.

full conversation at:

http://groups.google.com/group/red5interest/browse_thread/thread/77ae427d060f97df